# How to use same folder for multiple git repos?

Tags: git, github

i have git repo like folloing

```html
xyz
   abc
   def
      sample1.py
      sample2.py
```

i want to create separate git repo for "*def*" folder share it as another git repo and also want to use the same code as in my original git (*xyz*). like

```html
def
   sample1.py
   sample2.py
```

it is like having two git repo for the same folder. so i will update in single place and push the files in two git repos.

i tried to use the submodule, but i dont want to change any properties of my current project. i don't want to create submodule in original git , i just want to export one of the folder as new git repo.

Comment: Do you want to use a repository within a repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using `git subtree`. Here is link to a short tutorial of its usage: [git subtrees: a tutorial](https://medium.com/@v/git-subtrees-a-tutorial-6ff568381844) Have a look and see if it is to your liking.

Comment: Thanks, subtree worked fine. 
The following link also helped me
https://hpc.uni.lu/blog/2014/understanding-git-subtree/